# How to have totals row to be exlcuded from order by and show on bottom of table ssms18

Tags: sql-server, ssms

This is the code I have in place right now. There are 4 rows in the output table and I'm wondering how to have the totals rows show on the bottom of the table. Its currently showing on the top due to the order by DESC.

```
USE [MyData]

SELECT * INTO tableOne FROM [DataLib].[dbo].[Lease] -- carry over Lease table from Data Library to Reporting Database

--populate new table with the 3 commerical sectors and their uniqu
CREATE TABLE commercial_expirations (
    UniqueID varchar(255),
    PropertyType varchar(50))

INSERT INTO commercial_expirations
VALUES  ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / Sector | Industrial','Industrial'),
        ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / Sector | Office','Office'),
        ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / Sector | Retail','Retail'),
        ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / SectorType | Commercial','Total')

SELECT  c.PropertyType AS 'Property Type',
        e.SpaceArea_End AS 'RentableSF',
        FORMAT(e.LsDuration_WAvg, 'N1') AS 'WA Duration (Yrs)',
        FORMAT(e.[LsArea%_End], 'P1') AS '%Leased',
        FORMAT(e.[Year0ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS '2021',
        FORMAT(e.[Year1ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS '2022',
        FORMAT(e.[Year2ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS '2023',
        FORMAT(e.[Year3ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS '2024',
        FORMAT(e.[Year4ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS '2025',
        FORMAT(iif(e.[Year5ExpireArea%] IS NULL, 0, e.[Year5ExpireArea%]) + iif(e.[Year6ExpireArea%] IS NULL, 0, e.[Year6ExpireArea%]) + iif(e.[Year7ExpireArea%] IS NULL, 0, e.[Year7ExpireArea%]) + iif(e.[Year8ExpireArea%] IS NULL, 0, e.[Year8ExpireArea%]) + iif(e.[Year9ExpireArea%] IS NULL, 0, e.[Year9ExpireArea%])  + iif(e.[Year10ExpireArea%] IS NULL, 0, e.[Year10ExpireArea%]) + iif(e.[Year11PlusExpireArea%] IS NULL, 0, e.[Year11PlusExpireArea%]), 'P1')  AS 'Thereafter'

INTO ##Schedule

FROM commercial_expirations AS c
LEFT JOIN tableOne AS e
ON c.UniqueID = e.RecordID;

SELECT  [Property Type],
        FORMAT(RentableSF, 'N0') AS 'Rentable SF',
        [WA Duration (Yrs)],
        [2021],
        [2022],
        [2023],
        [2024],
        [2025],
        Thereafter

FROM ##Schedule
ORDER BY [RentableSF] DESC;



/*
DROP TABLE commercial_expirations
DROP TABLE expSummary
DROP TABLE ##Schedule
*/
```

Comment: `order by case when...`

Comment: Add `case [Property Type] when 'Total' then 1 else 0 end` as the first condition in your ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @stu If I were to use that, whats the syntax to not include rows where the name is total?

Comment: Why do you need all these temporary tables? Why not just a single query?

Comment: @smor still learning the ins and outs of the language. Do you have any suggestions how to have the final table be the commercial_expirations table?

Comment: `INTO ##Schedule` why do you need a global temp table here? Is it to ensure that two people can't run this query at the same time? Very few real use cases for `##global`, I suggest sticking with `#local`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand no reason. was just getting the query to work, then was going to go thru and cean up the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best attempt at converting all this code into a single query. As I have no database or schema or script to validate the query, i leave debugging to you.

```
with commercial_expirations as (
   select * from (
   VALUES  ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / Sector | Industrial',    'Industrial'),
           ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / Sector | Office',        'Office'),
           ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / Sector | Retail',        'Retail'),
           ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / SectorType | Commercial','Total')
   ) as x(UniqueID, PropertyType)
)
select ... 
from commercial_expirations as cexp
left join [DataLib].[dbo].[Lease] as lease -- why use a three-part name here? THINK!! 
  ON cexp.UniqueID = lease.RecordID
order by 
    case cexp.PropertyType when 'Total' then 1 else 0 end, 
    lease.SpaceArea_End DESC
;
```

Be wary of using three-part names. It makes your code fragile since it requires changes when using different environments. Generally speaking, your connection should determine the database to use for your object (table) references. I suggest you really thing about using FORMAT in sql queries as it is an expensive operation. Formatting is function best implemented in the presentation layer.

Last suggestion. Stop using this lazy pattern of <select ... into x, do something with x, select * from x> coding approach. Breaking complex queries into achievable parts is a good idea but that can all be done as a process of starting with basic queries against the tables of interest and then adding joins and functionality needed to achieve the desired result. Sometimes there is a reason to materialize the underlying queries - do that when there is a proven benefit. Otherwise let the database engine optimizer do what it is designed to do.

It is quite common to see people using the  pattern to simply push these scripts into production and move on to the next task - never making any attempt to clean it up or optimize it. That just reinforces bad habits. Start learning GOOD habits.

Comment: wow this is great. I'd say my approach this time through was very much a quick and dirty just to get to the correct output. Now that I've gotten there, I'll be going back and optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

To force the total row to the top, you can either add

```
  CASE WHEN c.PropertyType = 'Total' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

to the beginning of the `ORDER BY` clause.

You can also simplify and improve this query in a number of ways:

- Change `commercial_expirations` to a virtual table in a CTE
- Combine the temp tables together into one query
- Use `ISNULL` instead of `IIF(... IS NULL`
- Use `[]` to quote column names

  - Ideally you shouldn't need to quote column names at all, choose your names with care
- Order by an actual value, rather than the formatted representation

```sql
WITH commercial_expirations AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES  
        ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / Sector | Industrial','Industrial'),
        ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / Sector | Office','Office'),
        ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / Sector | Retail','Retail'),
        ('Asset / Most Recent Quarter / All Assets / SectorType | Commercial','Total')
    ) v(UniqueID, PropertyType)
)
SELECT  c.PropertyType AS [Property Type],
        FORMAT(e.SpaceArea_End, 'N0') AS RentableSF,
        FORMAT(e.LsDuration_WAvg, 'N1') AS [WA Duration (Yrs)],
        FORMAT(e.[LsArea%_End], 'P1') AS [%Leased],
        FORMAT(e.[Year0ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS [2021],
        FORMAT(e.[Year1ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS [2022],
        FORMAT(e.[Year2ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS [2023],
        FORMAT(e.[Year3ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS [2024],
        FORMAT(e.[Year4ExpireArea%], 'P1') AS [2025],
        FORMAT(
            ISNULL(e.[Year5ExpireArea%], 0) +
            ISNULL(e.[Year5ExpireArea%], 0) +
            ISNULL(e.[Year6ExpireArea%], 0) +
            ISNULL(e.[Year7ExpireArea%], 0) +
            ISNULL(e.[Year8ExpireArea%], 0) +
            ISNULL(e.[Year9ExpireArea%], 0) + 
            ISNULL(e.[Year10ExpireArea%], 0) + 
            ISNULL(e.[Year11PlusExpireArea%], 0), 'P1')  AS [Thereafter]
FROM commercial_expirations AS c
LEFT JOIN tableOne AS e
  ON c.UniqueID = e.RecordID;
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN c.PropertyType = 'Total' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  e.SpaceArea_End DESC;
```